# PDA with more than one initial state

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

I'm wondering if PDAs with more than one initial states are also accepting context free languages.

If found [that](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/24491/nfas-with-more-than-one-initial-state) question on this site about NFAs and would like to know if this answer is also valid for PDAs if one defines a new single initial state and connects this with the former initial states using  $\epsilon : \epsilon \to \epsilon$ transitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDAs that are allowed to have more than one initial state (let's call them PDAIs) are computationally equivalent to conventional PDAs:

- Trivially, every conventional PDA can be considered as a PDAI that happens to have one initial state.
- Every PDAI can be converted to an equivalent PDA with the process you describe.

So yes, PDAIs accept exactly the context free languages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. In fact, if we take out the non-determinism from the PDAs, then we end up with something that is computationally significantly weaker!

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_pushdown_automaton if you are interested about deterministic PDAs